# I can't find the problem to inject a service

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor-webassembly

I try to use dependency injection in a Blazor page, but it throws an exception and I can't find the error.
I will paste the codes of everything that I have defined because I look for an error everywhere and I can't find it, maybe you can help me.

exception:
InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'busquedaClaseServicio' on type 'AyH.CargaUI.Pages.Clase'. There is no registered service of type 'AyH.BL.Servicios.BuscarClaseServicio'.

Program.cs:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<DialogService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<NotificationService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<TooltipService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ContextMenuService>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AyHContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IBuscarClase, BuscarClaseServicio>();//<<<<<<------------ aqui esta registrado
builder.Services.AddScoped<IListaDeMaterias, ListaDeMateriasServicio>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IListaDeEspacios, ListaDeEspaciosServicio>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IListaDeClases, ListaDeClasesServicio>();
var app = builder.Build();
```

Blazor Page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Radzen;
using Radzen.Blazor;
using AyH.BL.Servicios;
using AyH.BL.Interface;
using AyH;
using AulasYHorarios.Modelo;
using AulasYHorarios;

namespace AyH.CargaUI.Pages
{
    public partial class Clase
    {
      
        [Inject]
        protected BuscarClaseServicio busquedaClaseServicio { get; set; }

        protected List<AulasYHorarios.Modelo.Clase> listaClases;

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            listaClases = await busquedaClaseServicio.BuscarListaClases();
        }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
using AulasYHorarios;
using AulasYHorarios.Modelo;
using AyH.BL.Interface;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace AyH.BL.Servicios
{

    public class BuscarClaseServicio : IBuscarClase
    {
        public AyHContext Db { get; set; }
        
        public BuscarClaseServicio(AyHContext ayHContext) 
        {
            Db = ayHContext;
        }
        public Task<Clase> BuscarClase(int año, string carrera)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public async Task<Clase> BuscarClase(int idClase)
        {
            var claseBuscada = await Db.clases.FindAsync(idClase);
            if (claseBuscada == null) { throw new Exception($"No existe una Clase con esa Clave Primaria"); }
            return claseBuscada;
        }

        public async Task<List<Clase>> BuscarListaClases(string año, string carrera)
        {

            if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(AñosDeCursado), año))
            {
                // Manejo de error
                throw new ArgumentException("El año especificado no es válido.");
            }

            List<Clase> clasesBuscadas = await Db.clases
                .Where(c => c.Materia.Año == año && c.Materia.CodCarrera == carrera)
                .ToListAsync();

            return clasesBuscadas;
        }

        public async Task<List<Clase>> BuscarListaClases()
        {
            List<Clase> clasesBuscadas = await Db.clases.ToListAsync();
            return clasesBuscadas;
        }
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
using AulasYHorarios.Modelo;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AyH.BL.Interface
{
    public interface IBuscarClase
    {

        public  Task<List<Clase>> BuscarListaClases(string año, string carrera);

        public Task<List<Clase>> BuscarListaClases();



        public Task<Clase> BuscarClase(int año, string carrera);

        public Task<Clase> BuscarClase(int idClase);
    }
}
```

I need the service to return the list of classes to later be used in the blazor page. Currently it throws me an exception, if I delete the line of code:

```
[Inject]
        protected BuscarClaseServicio busquedaClaseServicio { get; set; }
```

the page works correctly:

Comment: Why are you taking a dependency on BuscarClaseServicio instead of IBuscarClase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to inject the interface `IBuscarClase` because that is how you registered it in the DI setup.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Radzen;
using Radzen.Blazor;
using AyH.BL.Servicios;
using AyH.BL.Interface;
using AyH;
using AulasYHorarios.Modelo;
using AulasYHorarios;

namespace AyH.CargaUI.Pages
{
    public partial class Clase
    {
      
        [Inject]
        protected IBuscarClase busquedaClaseServicio { get; set; }

        protected List<AulasYHorarios.Modelo.Clase> listaClases;

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            listaClases = await busquedaClaseServicio.BuscarListaClases();
        }
    }
}
```